# Creating a "Shopping cart" with saved session

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, session

** Update **
I got the script to work, but I would like to have the option to remove the product as well...

this is my code now:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!array_key_exists('products', $_SESSION) || !is_array($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $_SESSION['products'] = [];
}

$productName = array_key_exists('productName', $_POST) ? (string) $_POST['productName'] : '';

if ($productName) {
    $_SESSION['products'][] = $productName;
}
?>
<h4>Saved Items</h4>

    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product): ?>
    <div class="echo-product"><i style="color:#F60;padding-right:20px;" class="fa fa-anchor" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach;?>



<div class="btn-01"><p>Offerte aanvragen</p></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
     $('.btn-01').hide().fadeIn(1000);
});
</script>
```

Ok, let me explain. On my website I have something like a shopping cart. A customer selects a boat and lets say (for this example) a boat type and optional items.

When they have done this there will be a couple of options left.

The visitor can now select to "save" the boat and the options by clicking on the "save this option". This option is then saved in a session, whit the code:

```
<?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["boat"][] = get_the_title();
?>
```

And echoed using this code:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['boat'])){
    echo implode("<br />", array_unique($_SESSION['boat']));
} ?>
```

Here is the first question:

This code works fine only if I save the first boat option (there are 3 (A,B,C)), then It says (if I echo it) Selected boat A. But when I then save the third boat it says "Boat A, B AND C" saved. It doesn't skip boat B then. I don't know why it does that. Does anyone know? And how to fix this?

Ok, second question. Same code. How can I make it so that the saved option is visible in the `div #saved-options` like a sort of shopping cart adding items and it would be great if they could be removed as well.

If I use this code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div id="saved-boats">
    <h4>Saved boats</h4>

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['boat'])){
        echo implode("<br />", array_unique($_SESSION['boat']));
    } ?>
</div>
```

Then all the boats are already saved. I can destroy the session using this code:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="saved-boats">
    <h4>Saved boats</h4>
    <?php
        // remove all session variables
        session_unset();
        // destroy the session
        session_destroy();
    ?>  

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['boat'])){
        echo implode("<br />", array_unique($_SESSION['boat']));
    } ?>
</div>
```

Then I it works, with problem 1 but ok, but I still cant auto update the `div #saved-boats`.

Is there anyone that could help me with these problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to make array in session. while updating first get that array from session, than update it, and save it back to that session.

Comment: Using this code: `<?php
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["boat"][] = get_the_title();
?>` I was told I was making an array? @RonakP

Comment: yes, so follow as I said. get array , update it and resave it

Comment: And would you know how? I'm kind of new to this stuff. I'm more HTML, CSS and so then PHP. @RonakP

Comment: yes steggie, this is because we cant directly update to session array, we can change the value of session variable only. So I think this is better to resave to session.

Comment: Is it possible to give me some reference or even set me up with a starting code? @RonakP

Comment: $stuff = array(...);

$_SESSION['boat'] = array('cart_data'=> $stuff);

$stuff = $_SESSION['boat']['cart_data'];

$stuff = // do your process like push or pop.

$_SESSION['boat'] = array('cart_data'=> $stuff);

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this...

```
$stuff = array(...);

$_SESSION['boat'] = array('cart_data'=> $stuff);

$stuff = $_SESSION['boat']['cart_data'];

$stuff = // do your process like push or pop.

$_SESSION['boat'] = array('cart_data'=> $stuff);
```

echoing your data.

```
<?php foreach($_SESSION['boat']['cart_data'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $value;
} ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. What could I put in the array. (everything I want I know). But what would you use. And could you explain what push or pop means?

Comment: push means to add new item in cart

Comment: pop means removing from cart

Comment: Could you tell me how to `pop` a item using my updated OP?